# Debugging with Arquillian in IntelliJ - Managed Container

Tags: jboss, junit, intellij-idea, jboss-arquillian

I've tried many times to debug a Test in managed container enviroment.

I get errors like *JDWP Transport Error*, *socket failed to initialize*. Means I can not initialize arquillian with the below *property* tag.

My arquillian.xml file looks like this:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<engine>
<property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arq.deployments</property>
</engine>

<container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
<protocol type="jmx-as7">
<property name="executionType">MANAGED</property>
</protocol>
<configuration>
<property name="javaVmArguments">-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=55407,server=y,suspend=y -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</property>
</configuration>
</container>
</arquillian>
```

Am I missing something?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 JVM running in this case. So this is a special debug case.

1. 1st JVM-> Started by Arquillian/Junit to perform the tests.
2. 2nd JVM-> Started by Arquillian to run managed Jboss.
3. 3rd JVM-> It's a **remote debugging** configuration that must be ported to JVM
   number 2 in order to debug 2nd JVM. Check out this [blog](http://rockycode.com/blog/debugging-remote-tomcat-intellij/)

So this is the idea, Run test (2nd JVM will be suspended until a JVM is attached to it), then run a new *remote configuration*, as soon as this starts, the past JVM will run.

It's a bit confusing but works.

Note that if you only have 2 JVM in simple debug mode, you will be debugging arquillian/junit JVM, which is not the one you are interested.

[image]